# How do you find the Taylor Series of $f(x) = x^{2}*\sin(\frac{x^{2}}{3})$ about $a = 0$?

Tags: taylor-expansion

Please without getting too technical, this is calculus 2. I know that the general form of a Taylor Series about 0 (Maclaurin) is: $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{n}(0)}{n!} * x^{n}$$ and so, $$f(x) = f(0)/0! + f (0)/1!*x + f (0)/2!*x^2 + f (0)/3!*x^3 + .... $$

Just very unsure how this one would be carried out and simplified. Is it simply taking derivatives? Can it be put into general summation notation?

Please help

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Taylor Series for $\sin x$

$$\sin x = x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!} -\frac{x^7}{7!}\ldots$$

$$\sin {\left(\frac{x^2}{3} \right)}=x-\frac{{\left(\frac{x^2}{3} \right)}^3}{3!}+\frac{{\left(\frac{x^2}{3} \right)}^5}{5!} -\frac{{\left(\frac{x^2}{3} \right)}^7}{7!}\ldots$$

You want $x^2 \sin {\left(\frac{x^2}{3} \right)}$, so multiply the above series by $x^2$.

$$x^2 \sin {\left(\frac{x^2}{3} \right)} = x^3- \frac{x^8}{162} +\frac{x^{12}} {29160} \ldots$$

In general :

$$x^2 \sin {\left(\frac{x^2}{3} \right)} = \sum _{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n x^{4n+6}}{3^{2n+1} (2n+1)!}$$

Comment: So the Taylor series would be all together this:
$$x^{2}*sin(\frac{x^{2}}{3}) = x^{2}*1-x^{2}*\frac{{\left(\frac{x^2}{3} \right)}^3}{3!}+ x^{2}*\frac{{\left(\frac{x^2}{3} \right)}^5}{5!} - x^{2}*\frac{{\left(\frac{x^2}{3} \right)}^7}{7!}\ldots$$

Comment: @yre  Yes, definitely.

Comment: What if I need to put it into a generalized summation notation?

Comment: @yre Let me edit.

Comment: $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n}*x^{2}*(\frac{x^{n}}{n!})$$

Comment: Might that work?

Comment: No. It's wrong. Correct one is very weird.

Comment: @yre Now it's correct.

Comment: Maybe this:
$$x^{2}*1 \sum_{n=3}^{\infty} (-1)^{n}*x^{2}*\frac{ (\frac{x^{2}}{3})^{n} } {n!}$$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57545/discussion-between-jaideep-khare-and-yre).

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**

Let $g(t)=\sin(t)$.  Then, $f(x)=x^2g(x^2/3)$.

Can you find the series for $g(t)$ and then let $t=x^2/3$?

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. -Mark